# Author names not centered in PDF

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, ieeetran

I am writing a paper which has four authors

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.

\begin{document}

\title{Important Conference Paper}
%\thanks{This work was sponsored by Infosys Foundation Endowment fund.}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Random University with very very looooooong name, Place } \\
 author.1@uni.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Random University with very very looooooong name, Place } \\
author.2@uni.edu}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 3}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Fancy R\& D Institute, Place} \\
author.3@fancy.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 4}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Random University with very very looooooong name, Place } \\
author.4@uni.edu}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Important Conference Paper
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Important, Conference, Paper
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The author 3 and author 4 are not centered properly, how exactly can I modify the tex mode to get it right?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but the [`IEEEtran` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) mentions a different format for the case of more than three authors. See end of page 5, start of page 6.

Comment: Good to hear. Feel free to post an answer yourself.